# Detect Graphics card details in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want to detect the Video Card Details like size, model and description in UWP.Is it possible to detect those details in UWP?

Comment: Take a look at this. Not sure how much info you can mine from it, but this is the verbose device list/information available to you in c#  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties